# Facing a rare issue in async method - .net core 3.1

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

we developed an API using .net core 3.1 with async methods.

here the issue is current object value has been overwritten by the subsequent request value.

example:

```cs
async Task function(request)
{
    var devUser = GetUserDetail(request.userType, request.userId);
    var response = await ExecureRequest(request, devUser.name);
}
```

in the above example

"devUser" object value of Api Request 1 call has been overwritten by the Api Request 2 call

is there any possibilities get this issue in async methods.?

please share me your experience and comments.

Comment: `devUser` is a local variable. It isn't overwritten, it disappears at the end of the function call. This has nothing directly to do with async functions

Answer (score 0):

The async keyword turns a method into an async method, which allows you to use the await keyword in its body. When the await keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete. await can only be used inside an async method.

"devUser" local variable is no possibilities get this issue in async methods.